# Does this equation also holds for complex parameters?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I know that the following integral equation holds

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx=\frac{2\pi}{b}\log(a+b)$$

for $a,b>0\in\mathbb{R}$. Does it also hold for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: I know this, but there a=b=1. I was wondering if anything would change when we choose a and b as complex numbers.

Comment: I would say that if you restrict to $\Re a>0, \Re b>0$, you can give an argument using (separate) analytic continuation (note that $a^2+x^2$ cannot give a negative integer for $\Re a>0$ so you can use the principal branch of the logarithm

Comment: I added an additional post. Good luck :)

Comment: Great! I appreciate that, thanks a ton :)

Comment: Thank you. It happened to be longer than I expected initially :) I should have investigated the case $\phi_A>\phi_B$, but seems that you are right and the formula works for all complex a and b. The only specific case is when $a^2$ and $b^2$ have opposite phases (i.e. lie on one straight line, but differ in sign) - we have another formula for this case (you may check, for example, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{x^2-b^2}dx$ $=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{b}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ for positive a and b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's investigate $I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx$ in more details. We want to know whether the formula $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx=\frac{2\pi}{b}\log(a+b)$ holds for all $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, or there are some limitations of its usage.

The idea of analytic continuation is that we would like to get a continuous function $I(a,b)$, if we switch from  real $a,b$ to complex ones by adding phases, i.e $a\to{a}e^{i\phi_a}$ and $a\to{b}e^{i\phi_b}$

Please also notice that the integrand is expressed in terms of $a^2$ and $b^2$ - integral "does not know" anything about $a$ and $b$. We could expect that $I(a,b)$ is in fact $I(a^2,b^2)$

Making change of the variable $t=x^2$ we get

$$I(a^2,b^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+t)}{b^2+t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(A+t)}{B+t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$

where $A=a^2$ and $B=b^2$

To make $A$ and $B$ complex we add phases: $A=|A|e^{i\phi_A}$ and $B=|A|e^{i\phi_B}$. We  suppose that $\phi_B>\phi_A>0$

$$I(A,B)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(e^{i\phi_A}(|A|+te^{-i\phi_A}))}{|B|e^{i\phi_B}+t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}\overset{t\to{t}e^{i\phi_A}}=e^{-\frac{i\phi_A}{2}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(e^{i\phi_A}(|A|+t))}{|B|e^{i(\phi_B-\phi_A)}+t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$

In fact by the change $t\to{t}e^{i\phi_A}$ we also change the integration path in the complex plane. But $I(A,B)$ does not change - due to the fact that both integrals along a part of a circle of big radius $R\to\infty$ and along a part of small circle near zero (radius $r\to0$) $\to0$ and there are no singularities (residuals) inside the closed contour (point $B$ is outside this contour due to our choice $\phi_B>\phi_A$).

[image]

Introducing $C=|B|e^{i(\phi_B-\phi_A)}$ we get

$$I(A,B)=e^{-\frac{i\phi_A}{2}}i\phi_A\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}+e^{-\frac{i\phi_A}{2}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(t+|A|)}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}dt$$

To evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}$ we integrate along the contour (below), on the both sides 0f the cut from $0$ to $\infty$

[image]

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}=\frac{\pi{i}}{\sqrt{Ce^{\pi{i}}}},\,\text{if}\,\,\phi_C= \phi_B-\phi_A\neq\pi$$
If $\phi_C=\pi\,$ integral is zero.

To evaluate the second integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(t+|A|)}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}dt$ we use the contour with an additional cut from $-|A|$ to $-\infty$ - to make logarithm a sing-valued function.

[image]

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(t+|A|)}{\sqrt{t}(t+C)}dt=\pi{i}\frac{\log(|A|+Ce^{\pi{i}})}{\sqrt{Ce^{\pi{i}}}}+\pi{i}\int_{|A|}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{te^{\pi{i}}}(t-C)}dt=$$ $$=\pi{i}\frac{\log(|A|+Ce^{\pi{i}})}{\sqrt{Ce^{\pi{i}}}}+\frac{\pi{i}}{\sqrt{Ce^{\pi{i}}}}\log({\frac{\sqrt{|A|}+\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{|A|}-\sqrt{C}}})=$$$$=2\pi\frac{\log({\sqrt{|A|}+\sqrt{C}})}{\sqrt{C}},\, \text{if}\, \phi_C\neq\pi$$
$$=\frac{2\pi{e}^{-\frac{i\phi_A}{2}}}{\sqrt{|B|}}\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{|B|}{|A|}}}, \, \text{if}\,\, \phi_C=\phi_B-\phi_A=\pi$$

Taking all together and switching to $a^2=|A|e^{i\phi_A}=|a^2|e^{i\phi_{a^2}}$ and $b^2=|B|e^{i\phi_B}=|b^2|e^{i\phi_{b^2}}$ we get finally:

$$I(a^2,b^2)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{b^2}}\log(\sqrt{a^2}+\sqrt{b^2}), \, \phi_{a^2}+\pi>\phi_{b^2}>\phi_{a^2}$$
$$I(a^2,b^2)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{b^2e^{-\pi{i}}}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b^2e^{-\pi{i}}}{a^2}}, \, \text{if} \, \,\phi_{b^2}=\phi_{a^2}+\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

To support the idea of @Conrad about analytic continuation.

If $\Re \,{a,b}>0 \quad{a}=|a|e^{i\phi_a}$ and ${b}=|b|e^{i\phi_b}$, where $\phi_a, \phi_b\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log\bigl((x-ae^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})(x-ae^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})\bigr)}{(x-be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})(x-be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}dx=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x-ae^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})}{(x-be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})(x-be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x-ae^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}{(x-be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})(x-be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}dx$$

Logarithm in the first integral has the branch point in the upper half of complex plane, so we close the contour in the lower half-plane (to keep the integrand a single-valued function). For the second integral we close the contour in the upper half-plane (integrating counter-clockwise along a half-circle of a big radius $R$ ). Integrals along half-circles $\to0$ at $R\to\infty$, and we get
$$I=-2\pi{i}\,\frac{\log(be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}}-ae^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})}{(be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}}-be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}})}+2\pi{i}\,\frac{\log(be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}}-ae^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}{(be^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}}-be^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}})}=$$

$$=-2\pi{i}\,\frac{\log(e^{\frac{-\pi{i}}{2}}(b+a))}{-2bi}+2\pi{i}\,\frac{\log(e^{\frac{\pi{i}}{2}}(b+a))}{2bi}=\frac{2\pi}{b}\log(a+b)$$

where $\Re \,{a,b}>0$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What about for the case `$\Re(a)=0$`. When I experiment it numerically (using python mpmath), it turns out that the equation is satisfied in that case too. Does it have an analytic explanation ?

Comment: @Sulam, seems to be an interesting question. I will check today.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @Sulam sorry for delay. Still working - I will present a bit later. It seems my knowledge happened to be not deep enough :)

Comment: No problem, thank you so much for your effort :) By the way, according to my numerical experimentation it turns out that the formula still works for the case Re(a)<0 when we replace a with -a on the right-hand side of the equation.